# Meaning of the phrase "go hard" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've come across it in the 4th episode of the 7th season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Negan: Now, boy, where were we?
>
> Oh, yeah.
>
> Your giant, man-sized balls.
>
> No threatening us.
>
> Listen, I like you,
>
> so I don't want to **go hard** proving a point here.
>
> You don't want that.
>
> I said half your shit.

Answer (score 2):

As Justin mentioned, to go hard means to try hard or put extra effort. I would like give some examples of the expression "go hard" used in different contexts:

1. If you're going to study for the exam, you might as well go hard and aim for the highest grade.
2. When you're training for the marathon, you have to go hard in your workouts to build endurance.
3. They decided to go hard on the marketing campaign to ensure maximum exposure for their product.

In these examples, "go hard" generally means to put in a lot of effort, be aggressive, or pursue something with determination and intensity.

Answer (score 0):

"Go hard" is slang for undertaking a lot of effort.  That is, it means to address some issue aggressively.  To go hard is to try hard, but it 'sounds a little cooler', you could say.  It's a bit humorous.